# How do I dynamically call a component or service by using variables?

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular, There is a way to call a component based in a variable I receive?

For example:
  If I try to do that with a method, it works fine

```
  const function = 'myFunction';
  this.myComponent[function]();
```

The program will Call

```
   this.myComponent.myFunction();
```

Is it possible to do the same but with component or a service?
     Something like:

```
    const function = 'myFunction';
    const component = 'myComponent';
    this[component][func]();
```

The program would call:

```
   this.myComponent.myFunction();
```

I'm doing that to avoid using many IFs, as I have more than 10 components to call or not

Comment: Can you please share some more code where you want to actually access the component. The 10 components are sibling of the current or how is the stucture?

Answer (score 1):

You can do just as you said, here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xb2bqi).

Besides that, this pattern of IFs and 10 components, seems like a code smell. If you want, you can post it here, and we can try to find a better solution for this problem.

Remember next time, to try it first, before making a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do. In your parent component template :

```
<div>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-home [state]='{id : row.id}' ></app-home>
</div>
<input type='button' (click)='click("g")' value="Call G"/><br />
<input type='button' (click)='click("f")' value="Call F"/><br />
```

In Component:

```
@ViewChild(HomeComponent) home;

click(e){
  this.home[e]();
}
```

In Child component:

```
  f(){
    console.log('function called')
  }

  g(){
    console.log('g called');
  }
```